# python mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql

Using the standard script (or any other) I cannot connect python to mysql.  I currently have the Python SDK for Windows from Conceptive Engineering (Python 2.7.2). Earlier I tried the free download from Enthought (perhaps adding mysqldb separately).  As for mysql, the lastest version is the universal windows download which is supposed to correctly install automatically(mysql-installer - 5.5.25a0.msi). I tried this after trying mysql 5.1, 5.0 without the one size installer (sometimes in 64 bit, sometimes 32).

In all cases, both python and mysql work perfectly individually. And I can see the mysql windows service running before I try to connect.

The main script can be broken down into two lines:

```
 #this one always works without error in ipython
import MySQLdb

 #this one never works, though all the variables test out in mysql fine
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", db="sakila")
```

## here's the ouput from ipython

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files (x86)\PythonSDK\<ipython-input-3-1ffbd20d17a9> in <module>()
----> 1 con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", db="sakila")

C:\Program Files (x86)\PythonSDK\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg\MySQLdb\__init__.py in Connect(*args, **kwargs)
     79     """Factory function for connections.Connection."""
     80     from connections import Connection
---> 81     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
     82 
     83 connect = Connection = Connect

C:\Program Files (x86)\PythonSDK\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg\MySQLdb\connections.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    185         kwargs2['client_flag'] = client_flag
    186 
--> 187         super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    188 
    189         self.encoders = dict([ (k, v) for k, v in conv.items()

OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

Comment: So you can connect to MySQL from the command line successfully? `c:\path\to\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p` ??  and tried all suggestions for [establishing windows connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) The most glaring omission above is that no password was passed to `MySQLdb.connect`

Comment: 1. password was tried.  2. I have opened and used mysql successfully, though not via the path style above  3.  I don't honestly understand all the establishing windows connections referred to above.

Answer (score 0):

1. is the db on the same machine (thus "localhost")? if not, use the proper IP
2. does the user 'root' have permissions to the database 'sakila' from the host 'localhost'? if not, grant the permissions

Comment: 1. yes, the db is on the same machine and 2. I opened sakila from the mysql command line client, so I think proves permission, as root is default.

Answer (score 0):

1. check whether your mysql server is running.
2. check whether the firewall blocks the port 3306.

Comment: 1. I see the windows service running and 2. I have turned all firewalls off and replicated the problem so I believe means port 3306 is not the issue